# Is there any difference in meaning between "still" and "so far" when used in negative present perfect sentences?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, adverbs

Could you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *still* and *so far* when used in negative present perfect sentences? For example:

> **So far** I haven't found a job.
>
> I **still** haven't found a job.

Comment: Still implies more impatience I would say. So far is just stating the fact "I haven't found a job yet", whereas still is more like "I haven't found a job yet (but I wish I had!)". I can't explain why though, so I'm just commenting. I'm interested to see what others answer!

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine, why do you think that is not an appropriate answer? It answers his question and is correct?

Comment: @maxbear123, I'll put it as an answer then :) I wasn't sure I should put an answer when I can't explain *why* it's like that. But I suppose he didn't ask that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still implies more impatience.

So far is just stating the fact:

> I haven't found a job yet.

Still comes across as:

> I haven't found a job yet (and I wish I had!)

Answer (score 1):

"So far" indicates a progress report. *So far I have sent my resume to 15 possible employers, but I haven't found a job.*

"Still" gives emphasis that something is true despite a circumstance or expectation that it might not be. This could be time, as in your example - *I still haven't found a job*. It could be something else, which is often explained. Examples are *They were down to 10 players but they still won*. *After the election Edward Heath was still the prime minister*. *He was told he had to do the job, but he still didn't do it*.